# Avoid recreation of an EMR cluster with Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-emr

> This issue is related with Terraform **0.12** version

---

Hi! I'm currently using Terraform to deploy an AWS EMR cluster in my team and every time we add new resources, Terraform recreates the cluster. The declaration of our cluster is the following:

```
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "emr_spark_cluster" {
  name = "whatever_name_to_emr_spark_cluster"
  release_label = "emr-5.29.0"
  applications = ["Spark"]
  log_uri = "whatever_log_uri"

  ec2_attributes {
    subnet_id = var.vpc_public_subnets[0]
    emr_managed_master_security_group = aws_security_group.emr_sg.id
    emr_managed_slave_security_group = aws_security_group.emr_sg.id
    instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.instance_profile.arn
    key_name = "whatever_name_to_ec2_attributes"
  }

  master_instance_group {
    instance_type = var.emr_master_instance_type
  }

  core_instance_group {
    instance_type = var.emr_core_instance_type
    instance_count = var.emr_core_instance_count

    ebs_config {
      size = var.emr_core_ebs_size
      type = whatever_type
      volumes_per_instance = whatever_volumes_per_instance
    }
  }

  tags = var.tags
  service_role = aws_iam_role.emr_service.arn
}
```

Basically we're using the `master_instance_group` and the `core_instance_group` as the [Terraform 0.12 docs suggest](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#master_instance_group) (**1**)

With the cluster already deployed and trying to add new resources, the `terraform apply` command says that **the cluster needs to be recreated** (removed all non interesting stuff):

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.emr.aws_emr_cluster.emr_spark_cluster must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_emr_cluster" "emr_spark_cluster" {
        applications                      = [whatever_applications]]
      - ebs_root_volume_size              = 0 -> null

      - instance_group {
          - id             = whatever_id -> null
          - instance_count = 2 -> null
          - instance_role  = "CORE" -> null
          - instance_type  = whatever_the_instance_type -> null

          - ebs_config {
              - iops                 = 0 -> null
              - size                 = whatever_size -> null
              - type                 = whatever_type -> null
              - volumes_per_instance = whatever_volumes_per_instance -> null
            }
        }
      - instance_group {
          - id             = whatever_id -> null
          - instance_count = whatever_instance_count -> null
          - instance_role  = "MASTER" -> null
          - instance_type  = whatever_the_instance_type -> null

          - ebs_config {
              - iops                 = 0 -> null
              - size                 = whatever_size -> null
              - type                 = whatever_type -> null
              - volumes_per_instance = whatever_volumes_per_instance -> null
            }
        }
      + instance_group {
          + autoscaling_policy = (known after apply)
          + bid_price          = (known after apply)
          + id                 = (known after apply)
          + instance_count     = (known after apply)
          + instance_role      = (known after apply)
          + instance_type      = (known after apply)
          + name               = (known after apply)

          + ebs_config {
              + iops                 = (known after apply)
              + size                 = (known after apply)
              + type                 = (known after apply)
              + volumes_per_instance = (known after apply)
            }
        }

      ~ master_instance_group {
          ~ id             = whatever_id -> (known after apply)
            instance_count = 1
            instance_type  = whatever_the_instance_type

          - ebs_config {
              - iops                 = 0 -> null
              - size                 = whatever_size -> null
              - type                 = whatever_type -> null
              - volumes_per_instance = whatever_volumes_per_instance -> null
            }
          + ebs_config {
              + iops                 = (known after apply)
              + size                 = (known after apply)
              + type                 = (known after apply)
              + volumes_per_instance = (known after apply)
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically the part that I'm really interested is in the `instance_group`. I suppose that's the reason why the cluster needs to be recreated because the current `master_instance_group` and the `core_instance_group` properties don't "reserve" specific instance groups but only the type and size of them, right?

For that reason as a workaround I tried using the [`aws_emr_instance_group`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_instance_group.html) resource trying to substitute the `master_instance_group` and the `core_instance_group` properties and link them directly to the cluster by the `cluster_id` property. As an example, the `aws_emr_instance_group` of the `master_instances`:

```
resource "aws_emr_instance_group" "master_instances" {
  name = "emr_cluster_master_instances"
  cluster_id = aws_emr_cluster.emr_spark_cluster.id
  instance_type = var.emr_master_instance_type
  instance_count = var.emr_master_instance_count
  ebs_config {
      iops = 0
      size = var.emr_core_ebs_size
      type = whatever_type
      volumes_per_instance = whatever_volumes_per_instance
  }
}
```

But at the moment of execute the `terraform plan` it fails with the following error:

```
module.emr.aws_emr_cluster.emr_spark_cluster: Creating...

Error: error running EMR Job Flow: ValidationException: Instance count must be greater than 0
```

I don't understand the error because I'm linking the instances group with the cluster.

So my questions are:

- How can I set specific instances to my cluster in order to avoid a recreation of it every time I need to add new resources (deploy new resources in another pipeline is discarded). Do I have to use `master_instance_type`, `core_instance_type` and `core_instance_count` even when those are deprecated params? Maybe I'm using wrongly the `aws_emr_instance_group` resource?
- Can it be possible that maybe that's the expected behaviour with the properties `master_instance_group` and the `core_instance_group`? I mean, to avoid create specific instances to be active even when the cluster is destroyed?

Thanks in advance

(**1**) *I say "suggest" because other properties like `core_instance_type`, `core_instance_count` and `master_instance_type` are in Terraform 0.12 deprecated*.

Comment: Do you run `steps` on your emr after it is created?

Comment: @srikanthholur I have not any `steps` property declared. Which type of `steps` can be declared there? I know that the cluster is used by other teammates to process files from a S3 bucket but they do that manually, can that action be processed through these `steps`? Also remember my aim is to avoid recreation of the cluster every time I create new resources